# Python 2 - Trying to reduce string by eliminating identical letters

Tags: string, python-2.7

Let's say given string is "aabcc". After this input is run thru my function, it should be reduced to "b", because aa and cc get eliminated. If given string is "aaabbccc", this would be reduced to "ac".

So here is my code

```
def super_reduced_string(s):
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if s[i] == s[i+1]:
            s = s.replace(s[i],'')
    return s
```

It keeps throwing string index out of range error whenever I attempt to update string s each iteration `s = s.replace(s[i],'')`. This also happens when I assign s to placeholder at the beginning.

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 12, in <module>
    result = super_reduced_string(s)
  File "solution.py", line 7, in super_reduced_string
    if s[i] == s[i+1]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Would appreciate an explanation and a fix.

Cheers

Comment: You are iterating through a string that you are modifying at the same time. The `for i in range` will go till i=5, but once you have done the replacement, your string is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

The first big issue is that s.replace(s[i], '') will replace every instance of s[i] in the string with ''.Using either s = s.replace(s[i], '', 2) or s = s[:i] + s[i + 2:] which will remove the identicals. Also fredtantini is right you still go to 5 even after shortening your string and that's why using a for loop is dangerous in this case. It is safer if you want to iterate through a string and remove elements to use a while loop.

```
def super_reduced_string(s):
  i = 0
  while i < len(s) - 1:
    if s[i] == s[i+1]:
      s = s.replace(s[i], '', 2)
    else:
      i += 1
  return s
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer!  can you help me understand why we increment i  in a else condition instead of within if?

Comment: Ya when you replace a character in a string with '', you are just removing the character. So with aabcc when you remove the first two a's, you get a new string bcc with a length of 3 where the 0 index is the b, so if you increment i in the if statement you are going to skip characters in the string. (This removal is the same reason your for loop was giving you the index out of range error)